# How to stream slurm stdout and stderr files to your stdout and stderr (live)

Tags: unix, stdout, slurm, stderr

I work in a server that is configured so that when you submit a job it writes `stdout` and `stderr` in two separate files, let's say `stdout.txt` and `stderr.txt`. The problem I have is:

---

How I can redirect these files live in `stdout` and `stderr` as if this process was running normally on my local computer (and I was receiving it's outputs)?